# Click anywhere on Gridview Row to display values in Textboxes using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I am unable to display the gridview row values in the textboxes. I have done this with C# but I don't want postback and update panel. I want it done using Jquery function. It still sounds easy, but the complex part is, I am using 2 panels, 1 having textboxes and the other having the grid. Clicking anywhere on the row should display the row items in textboxes in the other panel (CustomerId might be the clue), hiding the panel with grid. The code is below..

```
`<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSave">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblFname" runat="server" Text="First Name:"></asp:Label></td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblLname" runat="server" Text="Last Name:"></asp:Label></td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDesignation" runat="server" Text="Designation:"></asp:Label></td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesignation" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td> <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="54px" ValidationGroup="Master" BackColor="Silver" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" Width="57px" BackColor="Silver" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnFind" runat="server" Text="Find" Width="54px" OnClick="btnFind_Click" BackColor="Silver" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
        </asp:Panel>`

<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" style="margin-top: 0px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellSpacing="5" CellPadding="3" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" HeaderStyle-Width="150px"> 
           <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName ="FirstName" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName") %>'  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CustomerId") %>'  OnClientClick='<%#Eval("CustomerId","javascript:return sel({0});")%>'/>
           </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name" HeaderStyle-Width="150px">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandName ="LastName" Text='<%#Eval("LastName") %>'  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CustomerId") %>'/>
           </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Designation" HeaderStyle-Width="150px">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" CommandName ="Designation" Text='<%#Eval("Designation") %>'  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CustomerId") %>'/>
           </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField> </Columns>
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="Black" />

        </asp:GridView>
               </td>
                     </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" Text="Back" OnClientClick="JavaScript: window.history.back(1); return false;" /> </td>
            </tr>
       </table>
       </asp:Panel>
```

Andrei, check my last try!

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function sel() {
        $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> td').click(function () {
            $('#<%=txtFname.ClientID%>').val($(".FirstName", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
            $('#<%=txtLname.ClientID%>').val($(".LastName", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
            $('#<%=txtDesignation.ClientID%>').val($(".Designation", $(this).closest("tr")).html());                
            <%--{document.getElementById("btnBack").style.display="none";}
        $('#<%=Panel2.ClientID %>').toggle()--%>
            return false;
        });

    });`
```

I kept on trying and got a little success! I got the customerID by using onClientClick property of linkbutton. Now I am trying to call a webmethod (the method fills the textbox with row value w.r.t to the customerID) by AjaxCall.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  
    function select(CustomerId)
    {
        var id = CustomerId;
        var Panel1 = document.getElementById("Panel1");
        var Panel2 = document.getElementById("Panel2");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AjaxPost.aspx/Select",
            data: '{"id": ' + id + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                Panel2.style.display == "none";
                Panel1.style.display == "block"
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("Error");   
            }
        });
        //alert(CustomerId);
        return false;
    }
```

This is how I got the ID

```
<ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName ="FirstName" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName") %>' OnClientClick='<%#Eval("CustomerId","javascript:return select({0});")%>'/>
           </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Ok, and where is your jQuery code? Did you even try to write it?

Comment: Yes I'm trying buddy!
Check it, I have added a script..